# Firebase signin Annonymous always create new user on Unity Editor

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm working on unity + firebase project and I have a problem. when I use SignInAnonymouslyAsync on Unity Editor it works fine. but when I stop and play it again it always creates a new user for me. I trying to find the solution to solve this problem but I got nothing. anyone ever got this problem or have idea to solve it?